# Spring Security после запуска вылезает ошибка с цикличностью

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt

Текст ошибки, который выходит после запуска программы:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation
> report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
> 2024-01-09T10:23:14.857+03:00 ERROR 9776 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form
> a cycle:
>
> ┌─────┐ |  jwtUserDetailsServices defined in
> file[com.example.course_paper_backend\security\JwtUserDetailsServices.class]
> ↑     ↓ |  jwtTokenProvider (field private
> org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
> com.example.course_paper_backend.security.jwt.JwtTokenProvider.userDetailsService)
> └─────┘
>
> Action:
>
> Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are
> prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the
> dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible
> to break the cycle automatically by setting
> spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.

**Код программы:**

**JwtTokenProvider.class:**

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    @Value("${jwt.token.secret}")
    private String secret;
    @Value("${jwt.token.expired}")
    private long expiration;
    private SecretKey secretKey;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        secret = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret.getBytes());
        secretKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64.decode(secret));
    }

    public String createToken(String username, List<RoleEntity> roles) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(username);
        claims.put("roles", getRoleNames(roles));

        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + expiration);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(validity)
                .signWith(secretKey, SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(getUsername(token));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "", userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }

    public String getUsername(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secretKey).build().parseClaimsJwt(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authentication");
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer_")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secretKey).build().parseClaimsJws(token);

            return !claims.getBody().getExpiration().before(new Date());
        } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new JwtAuthenticationException("JWT token is expired or invalid");
        }
    }

    private List<String> getRoleNames(List<RoleEntity> userRoles) {
        return userRoles.stream()
               .map(RoleEntity::getName)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**JwtUserDetailsServices.class:**

```
@Service
public class JwtUserDetailsServices implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public JwtUserDetailsServices(BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEntity user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Пользователь с указанным username: " + username + " не найден!");
        }

        return JwtUserFactory.create(user);
    }

    public UserEntity register(UserEntity user) {
        List<RoleEntity> userRoles = Collections.singletonList(roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER"));

        user.setRoles(userRoles);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVE);

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public List<UserEntity> getAll() {
        List<UserEntity> users = new ArrayList<>();
        userRepository.findAll().forEach(users::add);
        return users;
    }

    public List<RoleEntity> getUserRolesByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEntity user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Пользователь с указанным username: " + username + " не найден!");
        }

        return user.getRoles();
    }

    public UserEntity findByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    public UserEntity findById(Long id) throws NotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Пользователь с указанным id не найден!"));
    }

    public void delete(Long id) throws NotFoundException {
        UserEntity user = findById(id);
        userRepository.delete(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не надо писать вопрос CAPSLOCK'ом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Круговая зависимость образовалась из-за того, что класс `JwtTokenProvider` зависит от сервиса `UserDetailsService` и "предоставляет" бин `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, который требуется для создания экземпляра класса `JwtUserDetailsServices`.

Для устранения этой зависимости по идее достаточно перенести создание бина `BCryptPasswordEncoder` из класса `JwtTokenProvider` в отдельный класс конфигурации:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    @Value("${jwt.token.secret}")
    private String secret;
    @Value("${jwt.token.expired}")
    private long expiration;
    private SecretKey secretKey;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        secret = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret.getBytes());
        secretKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64.decode(secret));
    }
// ...
}
```